# How to separate interface from implementation in Grails services?

Tags: grails, interface, groovy, service

I was wondering if it's possible to create a service interface on Grails and I can't find a proper way of doing it.
This explanation isn't satisfactory, since it seems to mix Java and Groovy:

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html

It seems to me like a bad design flaw of the framework, given that the interface mechanism is one of the best features of Java (and most OO languages).

Any idea to clarify this issue?

Thanks!
Mulone

Comment: What's the problem in creating interface in `src` and implementing it in service? Or do you want to be able to replace service implementation on the fly? Delegates (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Replace+Inheritance+with+Delegation) would help.

Answer (score 20):

You can have an interface, but actually you don't need one. If I understand you correctly you would like to have two implementations of a service and be able to choose which one to use.

Simply implement two services named for example `MyService1` and `MyService2`, then in `grails-app/conf/spring/resource.groovy` you can specify:

```
beans = {
    ... 
    // syntax is beanId(implementingClassName) { properties }
    myService(MyService1)
    ...
}
```

or even:

```
beans = {
    ...
    if (someConfigurationOption) {
        myService(MyService1)
    } else {
        myService(MyService2)
    }
}
```

This is how you tell Spring which service to actually inject for `myService`. Now you will be able to use `myService` like:

```
public MyController {
    def myService
    ...
}
```

and Spring will auto wire a proper implementation. This allows you to configure which service implementation to use based for example on some configuration.

Answer (score 5):

- Define the service interface in a class `com.mycompany.mypackage.MyInterface.groovy` stored `under src/groovy`
- Define the service implementation stored under `grails-app/services`

  ```
  class MyService implements MyInterface {
      // service implementation goes here
  }
  ```

Comment: but in this case can I specify in the controller "def myInterface"? How's the injection gonna work?

Comment: No, you'd declare `def myService`

Comment: How is the dependency injection going to know which implementation you want injected in your controller? As tim_yates says, you have to tell it, by naming it. During runtime you could grab another bean reference implementing your interface and assign it to myService, and thus having the same methodes available.

Comment: What if I need to inject a list/map that contains all services implementing a certain interface? Is this possible?

Comment: @IslamMuhammad yes, you can dependency inject the `applicationContext` bean,  and get all beans that are an instance of any type

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a good approach. However, I was thinking along the way that this is normally done in Spring where the list will be automatically injected based on the type  by declaring a list of the interface and annotating it with @Autowired but it appears that this is not available out of the box in Grails as far as I can tell, right?

Comment: @IslamMuhammad I've never tested whether that works in Grails

Comment: I am very new to Grails and I also haven't tested it but when I searched, I found suggestions of approaches like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493196/7228218) so I guessed that it's not supported out of the box. I'll report back if I test it.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a design flaw.  Groovy is different than java in that it is a dynamic language that uses 'duck-typing'. Whats interesting in groovy is that there are also interfaces.  So if you follow @don's suggestion, you can make sure that your service conforms to the interface, but the way you do DI with grails is to just specify the service implementation. i.e. you do not get the compile time check *where* you use the service implementation, like you do in java.

Note that there is no tight coupling here.  Coupling implies that something is bound to a type.  But with groovy's loose typing system, types are essentially dynamic creatures.  So in java, if you declare a type to be a specific implementation, the code might not compile if you change the type later.  In groovy, the code will always compile if you use the 'def'...(I think this is correct)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found for this is using **Spring bean aliases**. Basically you need to:

1) Create an interface in src/groovy ( `MyService.groovy` )

2) Inject your service wherever you need it:

```
class MyController {
    MyService myService
}
```

3) Create your regular services implementing that interface ( `ImplOneService.groovy`, `ImplTwoService.groovy` )

4) Add an entry to resources.groovy where you define which implementation to use (eventually, testing for environment, or anything else you need):

```
beans = {
    if (...development, useFTP, etc...) {
        springConfig.addAlias 'myService', 'ImplOneService'
    } else {
        springConfig.addAlias 'myService', 'ImplTwoService'
    }
}
```

[Complete sources here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/grails-goodness-using-spring-bean.html)

My comments: Using interfaces in groovy really seems like some kind of "I want to stick with some java stuff I'm more comfortable with". In this case, strong-typing. But it's exactly the nice part of groovy saying "No worries, you can keep the java way if you want".