# spring bean definition using interface

Tags: spring, grails

UPDATE: Duplicated. See [How to separate interface from implementation in Grails services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872999/how-to-separate-interface-from-implementation-in-grails-services/37892108#37892108)

I want to configure a bean by it's interface with Spring - as I would expect to be possible in a dependency injection framework.

Here is an example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
     public void callMe();
}

public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {
     public void callMe() {
          println("Calling MyImpl");
     }
}
```

How should I configure this bean in a way that I could switch implementations, for instance, depending on if I'm in a development/production environment? In Grails I would expect to fill my grails-app/config/spring/resources.groovy with  something like:

```
beans = {
     myBean(MyInterface) {
          implemented by MyImpl  //sintax not supported
     }
}
```

So I could define and use this bean in my code like:

```
def myBean
(...)
myBean.callMe()
```

I know there are some Spring attributes like factory-method and factory-bean to achieve this, but I'm wondering if there is a simple and direct interface like way of defining beans in Spring/Grails without boilerplate code to instantiate them.

Comment: The best solution I could find: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/grails-goodness-using-spring-bean.html

Answer (score 0):

The bean type needs to be a non-abstract class.

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyImpl) {
        // ...  
    }
}
```

You can still do DI based on the interface type if you want, but the bean definition needs a concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be more related to knowledge of grails environments than spring beans.

To call environment specific bean configs you may do it like below:

**Environment.current** give the current environment and hence

```
beans = {
     myBean(MyInterface) {
         if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT){
          implemented by MyImpl  
        }else{
          implemented by ProdImpl   
       }
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what I am actually trying to find out is what should be in "implemented by ..." and not how to check for the environment.

Comment: I guess same env. Thing could be used with implemented by